# Shadow map draw order

Tags: opengl, shadow, framebuffer

Following this tutorial here: http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Point-Shadows
I have a simple perfectly working omnidirectional shadow map.
Here is a GitHub source: https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/tree/master/src/5.advanced_lighting/3.2.point_shadows

However, as I change the framebuffer to store a float the draw order becomes important. **This is my problem**

Let me explain it better.

To create the framebuffer I change this:

```
for (GLuint i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
......
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depthCubemap, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

to this:

```
for (GLuint i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_R32F, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
......
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, depthCubemap, 0);
```

Then I change the fragment shadow map shader from this:

```
gl_FragDepth = lightDistance;
```

to this:

```
out vec4 color;
void main() {
....
// gl_FragDepth = lightDistance; // I commented this out...
color = vec4(lightDistance, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

*Which works as long as I draw the objects further from the light source first*. But if I change the RenderScene(Shader &shader) function to render the big room cube last, the shadows disappear!

This does not happen with the source from the tutorial which makes the Sherlock in me think this has something to do with the changes I have made. It would not surprise me if the solution to this is something trivial so, please, fire away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which works as long as I draw the objects further from the light source first.

Of course it does. Because you no longer have a *depth buffer*. Without a depth buffer, you don't have depth testing. And without depth testing, you don't have hidden surface elimination. So the last drawn fragment always wins.

That's *why* the LearnOpenGL.org code uses a layered depth image as its render target.

If you insist on rendering the depth to a `GL_R32F` image (and I have no idea why you need to), then you're going to have to have *both* a layered color buffer and a layered depth buffer. And your `lightDistance` needs to go into both of them.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I am going to research this better before I accept this as the answer.
The reason why I am using a GL_R32F image is because I am trying to get ESM working. But I am taking baby steps to achieve it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @stranded: BTW: What are you doing that you feel that you *need* the light distance to be in a color texture?

Comment: I edited my previous comment a second before you asked this question. Not sure if you noticed. But, anyway, I do not need to have the light distance in a color texture. I simply thought I had to if I want to have ESM by outputting _exp(80*lightDistance)_ ? Instead of just _lightDistance_

Comment: I believe this is the right answer to my original question so I accepted it. I will make another question related to ESM. Thank you, and @justus, for the help.